# How to add a swagger example to the fields in the asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

Based on [the Swagger documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/adding-examples/) I must be able to add some examples for my class fields, something like:

[image]

But I can't find any way to add these examples to my classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable [XML Comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments) and then use the `<example>` element to define an example. Here's an example of using an `<example>`:

```cs
public class CompanyValidationResponse
{
    /// <example>1234</example>
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    /// <example>Damage, Inc</example>
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The article you're linking to isn't mention the <example> tag anywhere, making it difficult to figure out which part of the article that's actually relevant. Could you specify in your answer how one enables XML comments? 

Answer (score 2):

#### Add documentation of multiple projects

I wanted to add a solution for how to display examples and other documentation when the types documented do not live in your primary web/ api project but in other *Domain* or *Model* projects as is advised by applying [Seperation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

I came across this issue because I usually decouple my *API* project holding the endpoints from the actual business logic which lives in my *Domain* project using [MediatR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR/) but my API might return types defined in the *Domain* project, therefore I still would like to document the returned types.

Here what the multi-project solution looks like (conceptually):

```
My.Example.Project.sln
|- My.Example.Project.Api
|   |- ...
|   |- My.Example.Project.Api.csproj
|- My.Example.Project.Domain
|   |- ...
|   |- My.Example.Project.Domain.csproj
```

In order for this to work you need to enable the generation of XML documentation for each of the projects you wish to include the documentation off by setting this in the respective `*.csproj` files:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <!-- Optional: Disable warnings for missing XML doc comments -->
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Now document your model/ DTO objects using `<example>` in the `My.Example.Project.Domain` project.

```cs
// A DTO in the domain project
namespace My.Example.Project.Domain.DTOs
{
    public class MyApiDto
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Unique ID.
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>b521fb69-d6fc-4c20-83bf-46a3f391eb52</example>
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Name
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>John</example>
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And of course you'll document your API endpoint in the `My.Example.Project.Domain` project.

```cs
// A controller in the API project
namespace My.Example.Project.Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api")]
    public class DtoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;
        public TextFilesController(IMediator mediator)
        {
            _mediator = mediator;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the DTO.
        /// </summary>
        /// <response code="200">API got the DTO</response>
        [HttpGet("something/{id}", Name = nameof(GetDto))]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(GetDtoResponse))]
        public async Task<ActionResult<GetDtoResponse>> GetDto(Guid id)
        {
            var request = new GetDtoRequest(id);
            var respone = await _mediator.Send(request); // returns the DTO from the Domain project
            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you just need to configer Swagger Gen to look for the `.xml` documentation files of **all** of your projects instead of just the one of the executing assembly as is shown in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments).

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo()
    {
        Version = "1.0.0",
        Title = "My Project API",
    });
    // Include docs from current API assembly (as described in MS Docs)
    var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{executingAssembly.GetName().Name}.xml"));

    // Additionally include the documentation of all other "relevant" projects
    var referencedProjectsXmlDocPaths = executingAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
        .Where(assembly => assembly.Name != null && assembly.Name.StartsWith("My.Example.Project", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        .Select(assembly => Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{assembly.Name}.xml"))
        .Where(path => File.Exists(path));
    foreach (var xmlDocPath in referencedProjectsXmlDocPaths)
    {
        options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlDocPath);
    }
});
```

In order to determine the *"relevant"* assemblies you can use `GetReferencedAssemblies()` on the current assembly. As your API will return types of your domain project the domain assembly will be referenced in the API projects. Unfortunately tons of other assemblies which you have not created will also be returned. As there is no concept of *my own assembly* and each assembly is just like any other assembly the only way to filter your assemblies is using their name e.g. using `StartsWith()`. Then create the path the same way as you would with a single file and finally check if that documentation `.xml` file actually exists as you might have projects referenced in your API projects which do not generate `.xml` documention.

Last but not least loop over all the paths you've just created and tell Swagger Gen to include those files when generating the OpenAPI spec using `options.IncludeXmlComments()`.

Now when you start your solution the documentation and examples should be displayed.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was struggling to find! :D

Answer (score 1):

To do this first you need to add XML documentation to your class. Here is an example.

```
namespace WebApplication44
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Display Weather Forecast
    /// </summary>
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Date of the weather
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Temperature in Degree Celesuis
        /// </summary>
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Temperature in Fahrenheit
        /// </summary>
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
        /// <summary>
        /// Summary of the Weather. It can be "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        /// </summary>
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Next, you need to enable the `Documentation File > Generate a File containing API documentation option` in the Project Properties in Visual Studio - No need to change the location.

Finally, modify the swagger generation code like this.

```
var xmlDoc = Path.ChangeExtension(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "xml");
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlDoc, true));
```

Then you will be able to see the Open API doc like this.

[image: Open API with Examples]